# How to convert a table with multicolumns from excel to latex

Tags: tables, excel, excel2latex

[image]

My question is that different cols have different widths. each row has multicolumns whose widths change. How do i have a macro which allow me to input such table from Excel to Latex. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know what it's worth, but you could try giving [excel2latex](http://excel2latex.com/) a try.

Comment: Hi @Andy and welcome to TeX-SE. Are you looking for a general solution to deal with any case or just some simple workaround? Normally I just wrote a cell combining Excel and LaTeX syntax using the operator `&`. I know some other tricks by they use Matlab, which is not a non-commercial software, and, since most of my data are processed there, it is natural to me to use it. I can load the .xls file into Matlab, edit it and then create a .tex file. I personally don't know any Excel direct to LaTeX macro or package. **If** this idea might be useful to you, **then** I present you my own library.

Comment: @KersouMan. Thanks for your reply.  excel2latex only works for default (or fixed width), not for variable width of columns, if i understand corectly.

Comment: @FHZ. I do have Matlab installed, I would like to know how you do it in matlab. Thanks.

Comment: I tested excel2latex. It works *but* won't produce exactly the output. Indeed, it is similar to [tablesgenerator.com](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables). You may upload a `.csv` file and *then* edit the merges you want.

Comment: Ok @Andy, It will take some time to elaborate an answer, which I also would like to show the basic workaround. As this main answer of mine applies matlab, I don't think it is suitable for this forum. Although, I will leave links here. I'll need two packages.
[Matlab to LaTeX Library](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/72155-matlab-to-latex-library) and [File Manipulation Library](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/71864-file-manipulation-library). One create the syntax, the other the files.

Comment: Check for now the functions: tab_num; string_add_lines and load_excel_to_matlab, save_file_extensao. But the format still needs to be manually specified, .e.g., `header = {'\multicolumn{2}{c}{c12}', '\multicolumn{2}{c}{c34}', ...
 '\multicolumn{2}{c}{c56}', '\multicolumn{3}{c}{c789}'};`. My approach with Matlab only work better **if** you need to repeat the process a lot. **If** you only need to do it once or twice, the internet gadgets might be more useful.

Answer (score 1):

I will summarize the simple solutions in this answer and write a Matlab-integrated in the sequence.

---

1. **Do LaTeX in Excel**: *Slow, difficult, high manual effort, susceptible to many errors, can be reusable but need copy and paste every time*.

This method you just built the LaTeX by typing the pieces you need inside Excel. That's was the first idea I ever had.
It will be useful only if you can copy and paste the data at the exactly same template.
But you will always have to copy and paste ... and it is incredible slow.

Consider the following spreadsheet

[image]

Starting to write the commands (*I made some mistakes when creating it*). It is easier to define the commands on separated cells.

[image]

The auto complete tool helps but not too much if you have many special cases.

[image]

Every merge must be manually correct and it is not simple to edit it correctly.

[image]

Then I noticed a error. `\hline` should be `\\ \hline` and then add a `\hline` only above the first row.

[image]

The result must be copied into your LaTeX editor.

---

2. **The services online**: *Good velocity, easy, medium manual effort, previews avoid errors, not reusable and need to copy and paste every time*.

> a) [excel2latex.com](http://excel2latex.com/)

It is faster, just drag your `.xls` or `.xlsx` file into it. But you might have to edit extra rows and lines are always inserted.

[image]

> b) [tablesgenerator.com](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables)

**The best option for few tables**, it has the tools to edit the table and generate LaTeX code. It has the slow down of converting your file into `.csv`, but the quick tools to format really payoff.

[image]

The syntax is presented and can be edited.

[image]

And adding borders is as easy as it is in any WYSIWYG software

[image]

---

3. **My Matlab-integrated solution**: *Fast after preparations, easy, low manual effort, errors are quickly corrected, the most reusable and no need to copy and paste every time*.

Another important backslash is that Matlab is a commercial software and I cannot say my codes work properly on Octave. Some of them use syntax I have never tried in Octave.

The solution is still not perfect, I usually don't have special cases to merge using `\multicolumn{cols}{pos}{text}` or worse `\multirow{number of rows}{width}{text}`. Although, I have coded a solution to the same problem in my `Matlab to Word Lbrary`, I still haven't made the same at the `Matlab to LaTeX library`.

*My Matlab-integrated solution is presented in another dedicated answer.*

**Edit**: I decided to integrate in only one answer.

---

So here we are with *our Matlab-integrated solution*.

To perform to full task, we gonna need three of my libraries

1. [Matlab to LaTeX Library](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/72155-matlab-to-latex-library)

To manage latex syntax and create it from matlab objects.

2. [File Manipulation Library](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/71864-file-manipulation-library)

To load excel file and to create the `.tex` file directly from Matlab.

3. [Search and Replace a WordSet Library](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/61226-search-and-replace-a-wordset-library)

This library is the master *Gambiarra* (workaround in Brazilian Portuguese) of all *Gambiarras*.

It let's you replace a given set of words for another set in as many files you want.
It almost the same as `NotePad++` does with its `Find Files` command.
But here you can do it programmatically and even taking advantage of the sequence of operations.

---

The `LaTeX` MWE is indeed very simple

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
    \input{input_tab_test}
\end{document}
```

The key concept is to ***always*** create external files, so that you only need to input it into the main file.
It let's you modify external files as many times as you want.

`input_tab_test` should look like this when we finish

[image]

---

The `MATLAB` code follows among the explanations.

Load Excel into Matlab, `'F5:K11'`is important to avoid extra cells. The second entry, `1`, is the number of the sheet.

```
excel_filename = 'Pasta1.xlsx';
[data, txt, raw] = xlsread(excel_filename,1,'F5:K11');
```

The following loop converts all entries of the cell `raw` into strings. I will probably promote it to a function soon.

```
% Analysis needed because all data must be string to the code
new_raw = cell(size(raw));
for i = 1:size(raw,1)
    for j = 1:size(raw,2)
        if isnumeric(raw{i,j})
            if isnan(raw{i,j})
                new_raw{i,j} = '';
            else
                new_raw{i,j} = sprintf('%g',raw{i,j});
            end
        else
            new_raw{i,j} = sprintf('%s',raw{i,j});
        end
    end
end
```

Then we define the format and call the first library function.

```
format = '| p{1cm} | p{0.5 cm} | p{1.5cm} | p{2cm} | p{3cm} | p{1cm} |';
tb_l = fc_lib_latex_cell_to_tab_line(new_raw,'\hline');
```

For repeated letters use:

```
format = repmat('c',[1 6]);
```

tb_l is the very same result from the online gadgets.

[image]

Now, a function with some syntax is called to add `\begin{tabular}`, `\end{tabular}` and whatever is necessary. The Matlab command `char` is the key here.

```
S = fc_lib_latex_struct_strings_02_table;
l1 = sprintf(S.btab,format);
tab = char(l1,'\hline',tb_l,S.etab);
```

`tab`should look like this

[image]

And finally we can save it in the disk with a function from the second library.

```
str_ext = '.tex'; file_name = 'input_tab_test';
fc_lib_save_file_extensao(file_name, str_ext, tab);
```

As I don't have a merge columns function right now, I will use the third library. This step makes the whole process less efficient, as the user still have to manually define the substitutions. You can be a little bit flexible as the example with `w1`.

```
w1 = 'f';
input = {sprintf('%s &  &', w1),...
    'o &  &  &',...
    'z &',...
    '1 &'};
output = {sprintf('\\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{%s}',w1),...
        '\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{o}',...
        '\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{z}',...
        '\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{1}',...
    };
```

To merge, I will create a cell with the row number and a vector with the first and last cell of each group to merge.

```
colMerge_p = {1, [3,4; 5,6];
             2, [1,3; 4,6];
             4, [1,6]};
```

But I still need to code it for the LaTeX syntax.

Finally, we call the function to search every `input` and replace the respective `output`.

```
filter = {'input_tab_test'}; encod = 'ISO-8859-1'; flag_copy = 0;
fc_lib_file_search_replace_wordset(pwd,filter,input,output,flag_copy,encod);
```

The variable `filter` filters only files of interesting.

This method works better when you don't have special cases, in the future this should not be a issue anymore, and the greatest advantage is the incredible speed to correct mistakes of to reuse with others tables with the same template.
And as it saves a external file, all you need to do is to recompile the main `.tex` file.

This is the result in LaTeX

[image]

**Edit 2**: *New function to automatic merge columns*.

Consider the following spreadsheet

[image]

Loading it into Matlab . The result of the command `tb_l = fc_lib_latex_cell_to_tab_line(new_raw,'\hline');` is

[image]

The new function to merge is `new_tb_l = fc_lib_latex_tab_line_colMerge(tb_l,colMerge);` where

```
colMerge = {2, [1,3], '|c|';
    3, [3,4], '|c|';
    4, [1,4], '|l|';
    6, [3,4; 5,6], '|c|';
    8, [1,6], '|c|';
    9, [1,5], '|r|';
    10, [2,3; 4,6], '|c|';
    11, [1,2; 4,5], '|c|'};
```

the first entry is the line to merge, the second has a matrix with first and last columns of each gap to merge and the third entry is the alignment. The LaTeX syntax is

[image]

and the final result is

[image]

Don't forget `\usepackage{inputenc}' to deal with accented characters.

Comment: **Edit 2**: Thanks @Andy for the opportunity to improve my library. I have already updated it on FileExchange. Any doubts, just ask.

Answer (score 1):

The times I needed to do that what I did was to export to CSV and mangle the result with some Perl scripting (a few lines do most of the job). Required touchups on the column headings and lines, however.